# Angular ng-if still run

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-if

Trying to figure out **ng-if**. Why is the alert function executed? 
Thanks

```
<div ng-if="false">
    <script> alert("a"); </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the `alert()` will be executed before angular is loaded. There is no `ng-if` at this moment